# cannot install and use module 'openpyxl' in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pip, openpyxl, python-3.7

For the life of me, I cannot install and use module '`openpyxl`' in Python 3.7 / Windows / and Anaconda.

When I try to run and or debug my program I am consistently error-ed out on:

```
    import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Although within my Terminal or Anaconda Prompt: It says its installed and requirements already met. *i.e. the below*

```
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)

(base) C:\MYSELF\language\python\MLTSS-PDF-Split>pip install openpyxl
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)

(base) C:\gitViews\language\python\MLTSS-PDF-Split>pip3 install openpyxl
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\users\MYSELF\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I have tried using `pip` and `pip3`.

I have tried using `trusted host`.

I get no error on the import line within Visual Studio Code; i.e.

```
import openpyxl
```

**Why cannot use this module ?**

Comment: In Visual Studio Code are you using a virtualenv ? if you are it will not have that module. You need to make sure your project is pointed to your systems python 3.7

Comment: Agreed with Taku_, this seems like a python path issue. You need to configure your editor to agree with your path.

Comment: Thanks @Taku_ How could I go about merging them? thanks for the help

Comment: I would start with documentation. This should get you in the right direction.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments it seems like this may be related to a pathing issue that you are experiencing within Visual Studio Code.

My suggestion would be using the documentation from them to ensure you are pointing to your local version of python and not a virtual environment which may not have openpyxl installed.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments